# filedescriptor out of range Exception after attempting to open multiple connections in parallel, over a certain limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pyserial, file-descriptor

### Problem:

I have a multi-threaded python application that is opening many socat connections in parallel. Once it creates a specific number of connections, I start seeing filedescriptor out of range error on the new connections.

```
Exception in thread Thread-601:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/user/project-name/pyspinel/spinel/codec.py", line 1252, in stream_rx
    self.rx_pkt = self.hdlc.collect()
  File "/home/user/project-name/pyspinel/spinel/hdlc.py", line 77, in collect
    byte = self.stream.read()
  File "/home/user/project-name/pyspinel/spinel/stream.py", line 70, in read
    pkt = self.serial.read(size)
  File "/home/user/project-name/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 565, in read
    ready, _, _ = select.select([self.fd, self.pipe_abort_read_r], [], [], timeout.time_left())
ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
```

I need to keep these socat connections open throughout the program, so I dont have the option of closing them to accommodate for the filedescriptor limitation.

It's worth mentioning when I check the number of filedescriptors associated with the app when it's running (`ls /proc/<pid>/fd | wc -l`), I get **1034**.

### Environment

Ubuntu running in a VM, with the following details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

### What I have tried:

Based on the research I did, filedescriptor out of range issue is a limitation of the underlying OS, as a result of having too many files open. I came across bunch of suggestions around updating this limitation on the OS, but I am still seeing the issue. Specifically, was following this [article](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ebrecht/servers/openfiles.html) closely. And ran the following steps:

- ran `echo "65535" > /proc/sys/fs/file-max`
- in /etc/sysctl.conf: `fs.file-max = 65535`
- ran `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`
- In one of the steps it says to make a local copy of /usr/include/linux/posix_types.h and update it so  `#define __FD_SETSIZE  65535`. And recompile the file, I am not sure about this step. I just made the change in the original copy, and did not perform any compilation.
- in /etc/security/limits.conf, added the following lines:

`*                soft    nofile          65535`

`*                hard    nofile          65535`

- in /etc/pam.d/login added: `session    required   /lib/security/pam_limits.so`
- ran `ulimit -n 65535`

And I am still seeing the same exception as the problem statement, after following all the above steps.